# export csv file with formatting in php

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I have exported csv file successfully by retrieving data from sql databases. Now ,what i need is show the data formatted in Excel like bold column names ,font color ets.
Please can anyone help ???

Comment: IMO: CSV files should contain raw data without any formatting.

Comment: your question is not clear enough - where do you want that formatting to be displayed? on a HTML page or somewhere in an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: yes ,i want formatting in excel spreadsheet. Please don't mind for incomplete info, i am really new here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV file cannot be formatted, Its just comma separated values file in a simple text file with extension `.csv`. Dont even think of it. If you want to format then think of exporting into excel.

Comment: ok, i got it . Infact i want to show it in excel formated. thank's Vins :)

Comment: Then mentioned it correctly in the question. Nobody is going to guess what you want to do.

Comment: tell me how can i achieve formating in excel , do i use some additional tags ? like html <b></b> etc.. or anything else??

Comment: @mansoor - you write an actual Excel file, not a csv, not html markup (else Excel will warn you that your file is not an Excel file when you open it)... use a library like PHPExcel

Comment: thank's alot @Vins ,I got the point. Before i was perceiving .CVS in a different way .